# LoggerFactory vs Logger

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a question I could not quite find a answer to yet. So what is the difference between the two lines?

```java
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

and

```java
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Which one should one use and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've tagged the question with both [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) and [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j), so I'm assuming that your project is set up to use SLF4J and that it uses its log4j binding.

If you're using the SLF4J binding in your class (having `import org.slf4j.Logger;` at the top), then you need to use `LoggerFactory.getLogger` (and you'd also need to `import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;`).

If you're using log4j directly (having `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;` at the top of your class), then use `Logger.getLogger`.

Usually the point of having SLF4J is to be the standard that you use for all your logging commands, and have it worry about connecting to the actual logging framework. So, if your project is using SLF4J, then use the SLF4J bindings. Or, if you just want to use log4j directly, then you can just use it directly, and maybe you don't even need to use the SLF4J library. (I'm a big fan of SLF4J myself, so I'd suggest using it for everything, but that's just my opinion.)

I'm guessing that perhaps your development environment is automatically selecting one of these to import, and you may even have different `Logger`s imported in different classes without you even realizing that they're not using the same one.

Comment: You mentioned using `Logger.getLogger` if we are using log4j directly. Did you mean to say to use `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger` instead?